# "central_bundles-xxx" in Nexus UI's staging repository

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-central

I just deployed my first project to Maven Central and found three repositories together with the one I staged. Two of them are closed and one of them open. They all point to some

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/central_bundles-1133/

Can I drop these repositories or what is their purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, today I received an email that repositories are shared among users and those entries represent other's data and should therefore NOT be deleted.

Comment: I have about a hundred of those... Could you elaborate more on their utility? I will not delete then, but 'shared among users'? What for? Should I ever push to then? I've always seen then there and I always need to scroll down to release mine. But my curiosity is killing me!

Comment: I have no idea either, it seems to be infrastructure bundles that are shared among users. Rather an implementation obscurity rather than an actual feature.